# How to transfer weight paint from bone to symetrical bone

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have my dog rig generated by rigify. Did the additional weight painting and forgot to turn on symmetry. Now I have left side properly weight painted, and right one isn't. Tried to symmetrize painting by removing one side and then symmetry in edit mode, didn't work. Tried with vertex groups by copying proper one, then Mirror Vertex Group, but it always shows some vertices are mirrored, other failed. Topology is symmetrical and bones are symmetrical too. What is best solution? On first two pictures you see left side which is properly painted, and right one which is not. Also, on third there are middle bones (spine) however, it isn't symmetrical to sides.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could duplicate the vertex group, mirror it, change its name?

Comment: Take the left one bone, in the Object Data properties click that small arrow right of "Vertex Groups" then copy Vertex Group, then you have _copy of that bone. Then, again click on arrow and press mirror vertex group and that is it. However, for me it doesnt mirror them exactly as I would want it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found is that you just remove half of the mesh which is not painted. And then use Mirror modifier and apply it. You have same mesh and weights are mirrored.